# C# program crashes when trying to allocate a generic array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, stack-overflow, allocation

Consider the following code:

```
    public class LimitedBuffer<T> {

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int DefaultSize = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private T[] buffer;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private int poe;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private int pow;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"></param>
    public LimitedBuffer(int size = 10) {
        // Buffer instantiation
        this.buffer = new T[10];
        // Value initialization
        for (int i = 0; i < this.buffer.Length; i++)
            this.buffer[i] = default(T);
        this.pow = 0;
        this.poe = size - 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void ShiftCursors() {
        if (this.pow == this.buffer.Length - 1) {
            this.pow = 0;
            this.poe = this.buffer.Length - 1;
        } else
            this.poe = this.pow++;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public T Value {

        get {
            return this.buffer[this.poe];
        }

        set {
            this.buffer[this.pow] = value;
            this.ShiftCursors();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString() {

        string ret = "LimitedBuffer = { ";

        foreach (T el in this.buffer) {
            ret += this.ToString() + "; ";
        }

        return ret + "}";

    }

} /* LimitedQueue */
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        LimitedBuffer<float> lb = new LimitedBuffer<float>(4);
        lb.Value = 1.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 2.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 3.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 4.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 5.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 6.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 7.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 8.0f;
        lb.ToString();
        lb.Value = 9.0f;
        lb.ToString();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
```

Well, in the point I outlined using "HERE" the program dies.

I am sure because, running the debugger, when it arrives to that line, and processes it, after processing that line everything crashes... I REALLY DON'T KNOW WHY!

Can you help me please?

Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is in your `ToString` method. You are calling `this.ToString` within it which causes infinite recursion and a `StackOverflowException`

```
public override string ToString()
{

    string ret = "LimitedBuffer = { ";

    foreach (T el in this.buffer)
    {
        ret += this.ToString() + "; ";
    }

    return ret + "}";

}
```

You probably want:

```
   public override string ToString()
    {

        string ret = "LimitedBuffer = { ";

        foreach (T el in this.buffer)
        {
            ret += el.ToString() + "; ";
        }

        return ret + "}";

    }
```

Comment: Believe me, that line in ToString was a mistake... it had to be el.ToString()... of course, when compiling, a recursion is taken into consideration. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @Andry it was quite misleading when you pointed out what line was causing the error when it really was another line ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `ToString` recursively:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string ret = "LimitedBuffer = { ";
    foreach (T el in this.buffer)
    {
        ret += this.ToString() + "; ";
    }
    return ret + "}";
}
```